# Spring cannot find the file via specified path

Tags: spring, file, spring-boot, path

My files hierarchy:

```
>resources:
    >static:
        >css:
        >json:
            >networks:
                >network-list.json
        >js:
        >img:
```

I've tried to create a new file via:

```
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("/json/networks/network-list.json");
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("static/json/networks/network-list.json");
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("../json/networks/network-list.json");
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("../../json/networks/network-list.json");
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("/json/networks/network-list.json");
```

...and some more. None of it works.

I'm still getting the

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: the system cannot find the path specified
```

What's the proper way?

**EDIT**

<strike>Found a solution. Had to include full path to the file like:</strike>

```
 File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/json/networks/Turtlecoin/turtlecoin-pools.json");
```

**EDIT2**

As TwiN stated - it's impossible to reference a file through `File` object as soon as the app is packed into .jar. A proper solution would include:

```
InputStream jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new ClassPathResource("/static/json/networks/network-list.json").getInputStream();
```

Comment: Your solution will not work when you move your JAR outside of that folder. You cannot use the object `File` to reference an object inside a JAR. You must use an input stream. If you absolutely want to use a `File` object, you'll have to get the resource's `InputStream` and create a new file using that `InputStream`, and then you'll be able to use that newly created file which will have been created outside of the classpath.

Comment: I get it. The path to the file could stay the same, right?

Comment: To get more specific, using the `InputStream` to create a new file would create that file outside of the JAR (in the file system), where you'll be able to reach it with a path. So if you use the input stream to create a file in your current directory (directory where your JAR is located), you'll be able to access it by doing `new File("someFile.txt");`. If you do that, it doesn't matter where you move your JAR to, it will automatically create a file in the same folder as your jar.

Comment: I've changed the line containing File declaration to `InputStream jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new ClassPathResource("/static/json/networks/network-list.json").getInputStream();`. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Yeah, if you can directly use an InputStream, that's even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("/someFile.txt").getInputStream();
```

where `/someFile.txt` is in your resources folder.

As mentioned in the [documentation for ClassPathResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html):

> Supports resolution as java.io.File if the class path resource resides
>   in the file system, but not for resources in a JAR. Always supports
>   resolution as URL.

In other words, you'll want to use the `getInputStream()` method for your case:

```
InputStream is = new ClassPathResource("/someFile.txt").getInputStream();
try {
    String contents = new String(FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(is), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(contents); // do something with the content here
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm mentioning this because `ClassPathResource` also has a `getFile()` method.

For more details, see [reference](https://twinnation.org/article/13)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("classpath:static/json/networks/network-list.json").getFile());
```

You could also use :

```
@Value(value = "static/json/networks/network-list.json")
private Resource myFile;
```

And then :

```
myFile.getInputStream()
```

(will only work on a class annoted with @Component, @Service... etc)

Comment: Updated my answere.

Comment: Same. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: the system cannot find the path specified` :(

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to load files from ressources :

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().
getContextClassLoader();
InputStream configStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("/static/json/networks/network-list.json");
```

Comment: When trying to work on the `configStream` is get the `null` pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give the exact location to File object. Another solution:

```
File currDir = new File(".");
String path = currDir.getAbsolutePath();
// String path = "C:\\ExternalFiles\\"; // Or you can give staticly
File jsonNetworkDetailsFile = new File(path);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not  a good idea. Resources files are supposed to be added to Jar.

Comment: Yea, it definitely has to be in a .jar.

Comment: I used this approach in my current Spring MVC project. It looked fine for me, till now. I think you are right. Your way feels better. However, I don't really get the problem. Your files are not going to change directory and as long as they are in the same directory, nothing going to happen, right? So what's the fuss all about? Am I missing something?

Comment: The thing is that the application is most likely gonna run on some server and not your PC, so an absolute path to one of your hard drives just won't work.

Comment: If you don't want to use resource folder, there is still better ways. Like use environment variables (standard in java), or a configuration server.